# Microsoft Surface vs. iPad for mapping

Tags: gps, software-recommendations, geospatial-pdf, tablet, avenza

I was recently introduced to the Avenza PDF app for iPad and I've been using it in the company I work for to help our field crews find their way around, and record waypoints and tracks. The app takes georeferenced PDF's and uses the iPad GPS to show a field person exactly where they are. It works very well and the field guys love it. The only problem is the iPad isn't synchronised with our Office media, which is all PC and Microsoft products, plus our field crews are now carrying an iPad plus a laptop which they need for reporting duties. If we were able to purchase the Surface then we could do away with the iPad and the laptop and keep the Surface.

So I've been asked to research the MS Surface. Does anyone out there know if the Surface has decent (if any) GPS capabilities? Or whether there is an app that would enable me to download custom made maps into the tablet? I've found Microsoft MapPoint 2013, but I have no experience with this program.

Basically I'm looking for an Avenza app equivalent for the Surface.

Comment: [Does Microsoft Surface have GPS?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfwinrt-surfdevice/does-microsoft-surface-have-gps/879e220b-4843-4832-b705-e87419328614)

Comment: If your field guys love it and the only problem is the Office interoperability it seems to me like you should be attacking this from that angle. I imagine that's a much more easily solvable problem, or at least one with a much broader audience.

Comment: just pair a bluetooth gps device - like http://gps.dualav.com/explore-by-product/xgps150a/ with the surface pro / ipad

Answer (score 2):

I came across this update from Avenza on their [website](http://www.avenza.com/resources/blog/2015/03/10/pdf-maps-windows-phone-beta-available)

The have made available (beta version) for Windows phones to be supported with their PDF maps.

In regards to MS Surface, it appears to now have GPS capabilities as outlined by ZDNET [here](http://www.zdnet.com/product/microsoft-surface-3/) also, the Microsoft web store, provides an app now [Maps Pro](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/maps-pro/9wzdncrfjcdd) which provides the capabilities you are interested in.